# List channels of a team including FilesFolder relationship

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the 'List channels' API call to list all channels belonging to a team and also retrieve the 'filesFolder' relationship in a single request.  I'm using the code below with the dot net SDK and v1.0 API endpoint.

```
await graphClient.Teams[team.Id].Channels.Request().Expand("filesFolder").GetAsync();
```

When this code executes, it causes an exception: "*Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Message: The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'Expand' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.*",
but the help states that the $expand parameter is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http .

I'd like to use the $expand parameter to potentially avoid many extra calls.  Is this a bug?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I forgot about this question and I eventually contacted Microsoft Support directly.  They informed me that the List Channels API method does not support the $expand parameter and that there are no plans to add support for it and that the help page would be corrected.  Looks like the help page still hasn't been corrected yet.